# IE9 compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, browser

If **a user has IE8**, but the website has

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9; IE9">
```

metadata. Does the browser still works in IE8 version or emulates IE9?

Comment: [Both instructions are meant for IE9+](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page will still render in IE8 and the browser will ignore the `EmulateIE9` setting is only used by IE9 to decide which doctype standards to use.

From this [source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx) they give the following example:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">`

This will tell IE8 to use IE7's document standards. IE8 doesn't recognize the `EmulateIE9` setting because it is newer (hat-tip to @edusysadmin).

When IE8 is used to access the page you are wondering about, IE8 will try to use the doctype set at the top of the page

Example: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Assuming the page is a doctype recognized by IE8 then the site will display properly.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 can render pages like IE8, because IE9 is newer, it knows how to do it.

The contrary is impossible. IE8 is older than IE9, IE8 cannot newer standards.